# Move an XML element from its place, to under another parent element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to move the location of an xml element and have it wrap around all the other elements under the future parent.

**Input:**

```
<soap:Body>
  <pre:getResponse>
           <![CDATA[
               <pre:Request>
        .......
               </pre:Request>
    ]]>
</pre:getResponse>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
 <soap:Body>
  <pre:getResponse>
    <pre:Request>
       <![CDATA[

        .......

        ]]>
    </pre:Request>
</pre:getResponse>
```

See the snippet below. Here I added a cdata tag to the xml and it wrapped around the other elements just fine. I'd like to do something similar only this time, the tag is already in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pre="
[Insert namespace]" version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="pre:Request">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>    
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. -- Note that CDATA sections are not parsed. IOW, there is no `pre:Request` element in your input XML snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment to your question, there is no `pre:Request` element in your input XML snippet, so it cannot be "moved". The entire CDATA section is just a meaningless string, containing no markup.

You could try removing the unwanted portion by string manipulation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pre="http://example.com/pre">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="pre:Request"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pre:getResponse">
    <xsl:copy>
        <pre:Request>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;pre:Request>'), '&lt;/pre:Request>')"/>
        </pre:Request>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/">
   <pre:getResponse xmlns:pre="http://example.com/pre">
      <![CDATA[
         <pre:Request>
            <payload>
               <item id="1">001</item>
               <item id="2">002</item>
               <item id="3">003</item>
            </payload>
         </pre:Request>
      ]]>
   </pre:getResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/">
  <pre:getResponse xmlns:pre="http://example.com/pre">
    <pre:Request><![CDATA[
            <payload>
               <item id="1">001</item>
               <item id="2">002</item>
               <item id="3">003</item>
            </payload>
         ]]></pre:Request>
  </pre:getResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

However, this could easily fail if, for example, the CDATA section contains another `</pre:Request>` string within the outer "wrapper". The lesson here is that if you need to process the response, don't send it as CDATA.