# Search for String in XML that matches its ending with one Substring and contains another substring

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I replace a string that is under a CData element in an XML? 
 Here I'm trying to match on 2 conditions like below:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[ends-with((local-name(),'mustEndWithThisSubstring'))] and not(contains((local-name(),'mustContainThisSubstring')))" >
```

1- How to have multiple conditions for the "xsl:match" section **?**

2- How to replace the string matched on(unknown) with the desired string(known) **?**

See the snippet below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-
section-elements=replacingWith"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[ends-with((local-name(),'mustEndWithThisSubstring'))] and not(contains((local-name(),'mustContainThisSubstring')))" >
    <xsl:copy>
            <replacingWith"/>
                       <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '&lt;foundStringThatMatchesConditions>'), '&lt;/foundStringThatMatchesConditions>')"/>
            </replacingWith>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input:**

```
<soap:Body>
  <pre:getResponse>
     <![CDATA[
           <foundStringThatMatchesConditions>
    .......
           </foundStringThatMatchesConditions>
    ]]>
</pre:getResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

**Output:**

```
<soap:Body>
  <pre:getResponse>
        <![CDATA[
               <replacingWith>
        .......
           </replacingWith>
        ]]>
</pre:getResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: You should know from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532804/move-an-xml-element-from-its-place-to-under-another-parent-element-using-xslt) that the content of CDATA is  just a meaningless string that cannot be addressed by XPath expressions other than string functions. That's beside the point that your XPath expressions wouldn't make much sense even if the target were a true XML tree.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I replace a string that is under a CData element in an XML?

Exactly the way you replace a string in the value of any other text node.  Which is to say, no distinction is made after parsing between character data obtained from a CDATA section in the input document and other character data.  All are represented as text nodes in the XPath data model used also by XSLT.  In fact, they are subject to merging so that no text node has another text node as an immediately following sibling.  `text()` is a node test that matches text nodes specifically.

Note in particular that the contents of a CDATA section has no structure as far as XSLT is concerned.  Where CDATA is used to embed XML in another XML document, the contents of the section cannot be accessed (directly) as if they were XML.  For the host document's purposes, they aren't.

XSLT 1.0 does not have a built-in function for substring search and replace, but you can do it -- with a bit of effort -- via a template.  Refer to the `substring-before()`, `substring-after()`, and maybe `contains()` functions.

You also ask,

> 1- How to have multiple conditions for the "xsl:match" section ?

You can provide multiple predicates or use boolean operators to combine conditions inside the same predicate.  For example,

```
<xsl:template match="@*[ends-with(local-name(),'mustEndWithThisSubstring') and not(contains(local-name(),'mustContainThisSubstring'))]" >
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="@*[ends-with(local-name(),'mustEndWithThisSubstring')][not(contains(local-name(),'mustContainThisSubstring'))]" >
```

Where the relational operator is `and`, the two forms have similar, but not identical, semantics.  Do note, however, that those particular expressions match *attributes* (`@*`), which cannot either contain or be contained by CDATA.

> 2- How to replace the string matched on(unknown) with the desired
>   string(known) ?

You may not know *in advance* which string will be matched against, but you certainly know in the context of the relevant template which text is being matched against.  In the expressions above, it is the return value of the `local-name()` function.  If you wish, you can capture this in a variable or pass it to another template as a parameter.  As I already said, it is possible to write a template to handle the job of string replacement.  The details are left as an exercise.